# Como puedo cambiar el estado de un checkbox en java?

Tags: java

Tengo un eliminar todo un checkbox que al presionarlo me selecciona todos los registros y al darle click me los elimina pero después de eliminarlos el checkbox se queda con la marca y quiero quitarlo pero no sé cómo poner el checkbox a su estado original

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void leeRifIdentif() {
    String RIF;
    int cont=0;
        TableModel model = datalistado.getModel();
            for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){ 
                if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 0) == true){
                    RIF=((String)model.getValueAt(i, 1));   
                    cont++;
                    try{
                         ps =cn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rif=?");
                         String rif = String.valueOf(RIF);
                         ps.setString(1,rif);
                         ps.executeUpdate();
                         MostrarDatos(false);
                         VaciarCampos();                              
                    }catch(Exception e){
                         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }     
       }
}
```

Comment: Efrain, Aunque parece sencilla podría definirse como amplia si no agregas más  información, por ejemplo tu código y a partir de él, los usuarios pueden realizar comentarios.

Comment: @Efrainrodc podrías agregar el código que ya hiciste, así vemos cual es el problema. Gracias

Comment: A que te refieres exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que estás usando un `JCheckBox`, deberías usar `checkbox.setSelected(false);`.

Si estás usando `java.awt.Checkbox`, deberías usar `checkbox.setState(false);`

Siendo checkbox el objeto.

Si no es ninguna de estas, busca en https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/. Quizás ahí encuentres el método que buscas.